# Al Header "Disposition-Notification-To" ¿se le puede asignar 2 o más direcciones?

Tags: java, javamail

Estoy trabajando con JavaMail, y deseo que el destinatario del correo pueda confirmar si le llegó el correo, para esto estoy usando la siguiente línea de código:

```
message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>");
```

Hasta ahí trabaja todo bien, ahora lo que deseo es que la confirmación pueda llegar a 2 correos, pero no he legrado que funcione. He hecho esto:

```
message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>; Nombre2<nombre1@dominio.com>;");
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar. no sé si es posible hacer lo que deseo, si es que mi sintáxis está mal, o del todo no es posible.

Agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según [RFC3798](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3798#section-2.1), deberías separarlos por coma:

```
mdn-request-header = "Disposition-Notification-To" ":"
         mailbox *("," mailbox)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, traté de hacerlo cómo dices:  message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>,Nombre2<nombre1@dominio.com>"); separados por una coma y tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: Probá con message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To",":","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>,Nombre2<nombre1@dominio.com>");

Comment: Lo intenté, pero el tema es que el método addHeader sólo recibe 2 parámetros. addHeader( "HeaderName", "HeaderValue" );

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, separado por coma si funciona, mi problema era el cliente de correo.